# How to diff int64's with pandas.diff

Tags: python, pandas

```
>>> pd.DataFrame([3,4,5], dtype='int64').diff()
     0
0  NaN
1  1.0
2  1.0
```

I would have hoped to not convert datatypes two times, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you need to, you can use [`np.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) -

> ### `numpy`.`diff`(`a, n=1, axis=-1`)
>
> Calculate the n-th discrete difference along given axis.
>
> The first difference is given by `out[n] = a[n+1] - a[n]` along the
>   given axis, higher differences are calculated by using diff
>   recursively.

```
>>> df
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

>>> np.diff(df.values, axis=0)
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1]])

# or as in your example:
>>> np.diff(pd.DataFrame([3,4,5], dtype='int64')[0])
array([1, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Note that you cannot assign this back to the original dataframe without introducing NaNs, and NaNs are of `float` type, meaning your result will automatically be coerced to floats.

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for!